# Creating a Compound Path in Android like Adobe illustrator

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

**Like the image on the right,
I want to treat multiple separated shapes as 1 shape in the color gradient behavior!
Any Ideas?!**

[image: Comparison]

Answer (score 0):

That is like four separate squares, so no compound shapes? In any case ShapeDrawable, those SVG-like XML vector drawing tools, with clips at the end.